# How do I correctly use std::mutex in C++ without deadlocks and/or races?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, mutex

I am trying to debug a program that I am trying to run in parallel. I am at a loss for why I have both deadlocks and race conditions when I attempt to compile and run the code in C++. Here is all the relevant code that I have written thus far.

```
// define job struct here

// define mutex, condition variable, deque, and atomic here
std::deque<job> jobList;
std::mutex jobMutex;
std::condition_variable jobCondition;
std::atomic<int> numberThreadsRunning;

void addJobs(...insert parameters here...)
{
        job current = {...insert parameters here...};
        jobMutex.lock();
        std::cout << "We have successfully acquired the mutex." << std::endl;
        jobList.push_back(current);
        jobCondition.notify_one();
        jobMutex.unlock();
        std::cout << "We have successfully unlocked the mutex." << std::endl;
}

void work(void) {
        job* current;
        numberThreadsRunning++;
        while (true) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
                if (jobList.empty()) {
                        numberThreadsRunning--;
                        jobCondition.wait(lock);
                        numberThreadsRunning++;
                }
                current = &jobList.at(0);
                jobList.pop_front();
                jobMutex.unlock();

                std::cout << "We are now going to start a job." << std::endl;

                ////Call an expensive function for the current job that we want to run in parallel.
                ////This could either complete the job, or spawn more jobs, by calling addJobs. 
                ////This recursive behavior typically results in there being thousands of jobs.

                std::cout << "We have successfully completed a job." << std::endl;
        }
        numberThreadsRunning--;
        std::cout << "There are now " << numberThreadsRunning << " threads running." << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
        //Initialize everything and add first job to the deque.
        std::thread jobThreads[n]

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                jobThreads[i] = std::thread(work);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                jobThreads[i].join();
        }
 }
```

The code compiles, but depending on random factors, it will either deadlock at the very end or have a segmentation fault in the middle while the queue is still quite large. Does anyone know more about why this is happening?

...

EDIT:
I have edited this question to include additional information and a more complete example. While I certainly don't want to bore you with the thousands of lines of code I actually have (an image rendering package), I believe this example better represents the type of problem I am facing. The example given in the answer by Alan Birtles only works on very simple job structure with very simple functionality. In the actual job struct, there are multiple pointers to different vectors and matrices, and therefore we need pointers to the job struct, otherwise the compiler would fail to compile because the constructor function was "implicitly deleted".

I believe the error I am facing has to do with the way I am locking and unlocking the threads. I know that the pointers are also causing some issues, but they probably have to stay. The function `thisFunction()` represents the function that needs to be run in parallel.

```
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct job {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>   &matrix;
        int num;
};
bool closed = false;

std::deque<job> jobList;
std::mutex jobMutex;
std::condition_variable jobCondition;
std::atomic<int> numberThreadsRunning;
std::atomic<int> numJobs;

struct tcout
{
    tcout() :lock(mutex) {}

    template < typename T >
    tcout& operator<< (T&& t)
    {
        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }

    static std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock;
};
std::mutex tcout::mutex;


std::vector<std::vector<int>> multiply4x4(
                std::vector<std::vector<int>> &A,
                std::vector<std::vector<int>> &B) {
        //Only deals with 4x4 matrices
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> C(4, std::vector<int>(4, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                                C.at(i).at(j) = C.at(i).at(j) + A.at(i).at(k) * B.at(k).at(j);
                        }
                }
        }

        return C;
}

void addJobs()
{
    numJobs++;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(4, std::vector<int>(4, -1)); //Create random 4x4 matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    matrix.at(i).at(j) = rand() % 10 + 1;
            }
    }
    job current = { matrix, numJobs };
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);

    std::cout << "The matrix for job " << current.num << " is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    std::cout << matrix.at(i).at(j) << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
    }

    jobList.push_back(current);
    jobCondition.notify_one();
    lock.unlock();
}

void thisFunction(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &matrix, int num)
{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand() * 500 / RAND_MAX));
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> product = matrix;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(jobMutex);
        std::cout << "The imported matrix for job " << num << " is: \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        std::cout << product.at(i).at(j) << "\t";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
        }
        lk.unlock();

        int power;
        if (num % 2 == 1) {
                power = 3;
        } else if (num % 2 == 0) {
                power = 2;
                addJobs();
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < power; k++) {
                product = multiply4x4(product, matrix);
        }

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
        std::cout << "The matrix for job " << num << " to the power of " << power << " is: \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        std::cout << product.at(i).at(j) << "\t";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
        }
        lock.unlock();

}

void work(void) {
    job *current;
    numberThreadsRunning++;
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
        if (jobList.empty()) {
            numberThreadsRunning--;
            jobCondition.wait(lock, [] {return !jobList.empty() || closed; });
            numberThreadsRunning++;
        }
        if (jobList.empty())
        {
            break;
        }
        current = &jobList.front();
        job newcurrent = {current->matrix, current->num};
        current = &newcurrent;
        jobList.pop_front();
        lock.unlock();
        thisFunction(current->matrix, current->num);
        tcout() << "job " << current->num << " complete\n";
    }
    numberThreadsRunning--;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const size_t n = 1;
    numJobs = 0;
    std::thread jobThreads[n];
    std::vector<int> buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        jobThreads[i] = std::thread(work);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        addJobs();
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
        closed = true;
        jobCondition.notify_all();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        jobThreads[i].join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor point concerning your title... you appear to be using `std::mutex` not implementing it.  The author/maintainer(s) of the standard library implement it.

Comment: I don't think this code will compile. Unless "...insert parameters here..." has a meaning with which I'm not familiar ...

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: I have modified the question to make it less vague.

Comment: If you remove the reference in your `job` struct everything works for me, you can't keep references to variables that no longer exist, I'll repeat what I said in my answer, if you want to avoid copies you need to use smart pointers

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fully working example:

```
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct job { int num; };
bool closed = false;

std::deque<job> jobList;
std::mutex jobMutex;
std::condition_variable jobCondition;
std::atomic<int> numberThreadsRunning;

struct tcout
{
    tcout() :lock(mutex) {}

    template < typename T >
    tcout& operator<< (T&& t)
    {
        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }

    static std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock;
};
std::mutex tcout::mutex;

void addJobs()
{
    static int num = 0;
    job current = { num++ };
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
    jobList.push_back(current);
    jobCondition.notify_one();
    lock.unlock();
}

void work(void) {
    job current;
    numberThreadsRunning++;
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
        if (jobList.empty()) {
            numberThreadsRunning--;
            jobCondition.wait(lock, [] {return !jobList.empty() || closed; });
            numberThreadsRunning++;
        }
        if (jobList.empty())
        {
            break;
        }
        current = jobList.front();
        jobList.pop_front();
        lock.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand() * 500 / RAND_MAX));
        tcout() << "job " << current.num << " complete\n";
    }
    numberThreadsRunning--;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const size_t n = 4;
    std::thread jobThreads[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        jobThreads[i] = std::thread(work);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        addJobs();
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(jobMutex);
        closed = true;
        jobCondition.notify_all();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        jobThreads[i].join();
    }
}
```

I've made the following changes:

1. Never call `lock()` or `unlock()` on a `std::mutex`, always use `std::unique_lock` (or similar classes). You were calling `jobMutex.unlock()` in `work()` for the mutex you had locked with `std::unique_lock`, `std::unique_lock` would then call unlock for the second time leading to undefined behaviour. If an exception was thrown in `addJobs` then as you weren't using `std::unique_lock` at all the mutex would remain locked.
2. You need to use a predicate for `jobCondition.wait` otherwise a spurious wakeup could cause the wait to return while `jobList` is still empty.
3. I've added a `closed` variable to make the program exit when there's no more work to do
4. I've added a definition of `job`
5. In `work` you take a pointer to an item on the queue then pop it off the queue, as the item no longer exists the pointer is dangling. You need to copy the item before popping the queue. If you want to avoid the copy either make your `job` structure movable or change your queue to store `std::unique_ptr<job>` or `std::shared_ptr<job>`
6. I've also added a thread safe version of `std::cout`, this isn't strictly necessary but stops your output lines overlapping each other. Ideally you should use a proper thread safe logging library instead as locking a mutex for every print is expensive and if you have enough prints will make your program practically single threaded

Comment: Note that even if your platform guarantees no spurious wakeups, you still need a predicate for the wait. Imagine if two jobs are queued, two threads are woken, and the first thread does both jobs before the second thread gets scheduled. Even though the second thread's wakeup was not spurious, it can still find the job queue empty. Without the predicate check, that thread would terminate erroneously.

Comment: I have updated the original code with these points in mind, however it doesn't fully solve the problem. I have tried to clarify the problem a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `job* current;` with `job current;` and then `current = jobList.at(0);`. Otherwise you end up with a pointer to an element of `jobList` that does not exist after `jobList.pop_front()`.

Replace `if (jobList.empty())` with `while(jobList.empty())` to handle spurious wakeups.